# Spring - addResourceHandlers not resolving the static resources with Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following problem. When configuring my Spring WebMVC application with ResourceHandlers and having a RestController class with a special `@RequestMapping`, the static resource will not be served, instead the RestController is being called.

Here is the code:

```
@Configuration
@ServletComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ServletContextAware, WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(new Class[]{Main.class, Initializer.class, ContainerInitializer.class});
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new FacesServlet(), "*.jsf");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("JSF Faces Servlet");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistratiton() {
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new FacesServlet(), new String[]{"*.xhtml"});
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("XHTML Faces Servlet");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

       // Register resource handler for CSS and JS
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic())
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());

       // Register resource handler for images
       registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/images/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic())
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

So I have two resource handlers for serving static resources like css, js files in the resources folder and an images folder for my static images.

The code for my RestController class looks as follows:

```
@RestController
@Component
public class Clownfish {
   @GetMapping(path = "/{name}/**")
   public void universalGet(@PathVariable("name") String name, @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
         String path = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
         if (name.compareToIgnoreCase(path) != 0) {
             name = path.substring(1);
         }
    }
}
```

When calling my resource with http://localhost:8080/images/foo.png the RestController is being called.
If I change `@GetMapping(path = "/{name}/**")` to `@GetMapping(path = "/{name}")` it works correctly. But I need the wildcards to handle special calls.

What am I doing wrong in my configuration?
TIA

Comment: take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex

Comment: Reading the documentation doesn't solve my problem. As I wrote, I need the wildcard. The ``name`` is the universal part of getting a site in my CMS and the wildcard is needed to also serve aliase to that site. 
I thought that there could be something, that gives the ResourceHandler a higher priority than the REST Controller.
If nothing helps at all, I need to process my static content directly in my REST Controller as well.

Comment: Okay. I got it solved. Setting the ResourceHandler priority to -1 does the job.
``registry.setOrder(-1);``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to set the priority of the ResourceHandler.

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

       // Register resource handler for CSS and JS
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic())
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());

       // Register resource handler for images
       registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/images/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic())
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
       registry.setOrder(-1);  // This will set the priority lower to the default handler (that is by default 0)
    }
```